# Restricting linespread outside some environments

Tags: line-spacing

I need to fix a precise linespread in a document I'm writing, but only in the plain sections of the document. In other words, I'm writing math and in the text there are a lot of environments (theorem, proposition, definition, etc): is there a way to make linespread work only OUTSIDE these environments, without inserting a command every time I use an environment?

I guess I could redefine all the environments at the beginning of my document, is there an easier way to do this?

Comment: Perhaps use `etoolbox` and `setspace` and write in your preamble things like: `\AtBeginEnvironment{mytheorem}{\singlespacing}`, or `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mytheorem}{\singlespacing}`, and `\AtEndEnvironment{mytheorem}{\linespread{…}}`, or `\AfterEndEnvironment{mytheorem}{\linespread{…}}`.

Comment: Perfect! May I suggest  you should use `\setspace{…}` rather than `\linespread{…}` as this kind of modifications have side effects that  `setspace`takes into account (cf. `l2tabu`).

Comment: @Bernard: I think you should make an answer out of your comment ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `etoolbox` and `setspace` and write in your preamble things like:

```
\AtBeginEnvironment{mytheorem}{\singlespacing}
```

or `\BeforeBeginEnvironment{mytheorem}{\singlespacing}` (not tested which one works — see the documentation of etoolbox).

and restore the document global spacing with:

```
\AtEndEnvironment{mytheorem}{\linespread{…}}
```

or `\AfterEndEnvironment{mytheorem}{\linespread{…}}`

Comment aside, you should probably use the `\setspace{…}` command (from the homonymous package) rather than `\linespread`, as there are a number of side effects the package takes care of. See the details in `l2tabu`, §1.4.